# Why tokenURI need gas fees?

Tags: solidity, ether, nft, polygon

I want to retrieve `metadataURI`, but I got this error

```
cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":61,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"execution reverted\"}}","error":{"code":-32000},"requestBody":"{\"method\":\"eth_call\",\"params\":[{\"to\":\"0x5fbdb2315678afecb367f032d93f642f64180aa3\",\"data\":\"0xc87b56dd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001\"},\"latest\"],\"id\":61,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com"}, method="call", transaction={"to":"0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3","data":"0xc87b56dd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001","accessList":null}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.2.0)
```

**Code**

```
async function getNFT({contract, provider, tokenId}) {
  console.log(tokenId)
  console.log(contract)
  const metadataURI = await contract.tokenURI(tokenId);
  // const metadata = await fetchIPFSJSON(metadataURI);
  // console.log('metadata: ', metadata)

  // if (metadata.image) {
  //   metadata.image = makeGatewayURL(metadata.image);
  // }

  // return metadata;
}
```

Here my console log

[image]

Comment: Did you try `contract.tokenURI(tokenId).call()`

Comment: can you show tokenURI() function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tokenURI() does not require to spend gas since its a view function;

The EVM is returning an error message "Execution reverted" which means that you're actually calling the contract correctly but there is something wrong with the logic; This narrows down the problem to the tokenURI() function

PLease add the tokenURI code to your question to keep troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the token is still not minted.
Cross verify it once and also that your rpc-network is correct.